# What's the return type of an anonymous class

Tags: c#

I have a class that used to have a string return type. Now I find I need to return more than a string. I was thinking to return something like below:

```
public string Test()
{
  return ( new { ID = 5, Name= "Dave" } );
}
```

Is this even possible and if so then what would be the return type? I know it's not string ..

Comment: If you have created an anonymous `object` the return type surely will be `object`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object that you return does have a class, but it's anonymous so you can't specify it in the code. You just have to return it as an `object` reference:

```
public object Test() {
  return new { ID = 5, Name= "Dave" };
}
```

Note that the anonymous type is unknown outside the scope of the method, so reflection is the only way to access its properties.

If you want to be able to use the returned object conveniently, you should declare a class:

```
public class TestResult
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public TestResult Test() {
    return new TestResult() { ID = 5, Name= "Dave" };
}
```

Another alternative is to use an existing class, if it fits your purpose. A `KeyValuePair` is close to what you use, but then the properties will of course be named `Key` and `Value` instead of `ID` and `Name`:

```
public KeyValuePair<int, string> Test() {
  return new KeyValuePair<int, string>(5, "Dave");
}
```

Comment: Not 100% correct: technically, the anonymous type is scoped to the enclosing type, not just the method. Therefore, it is known to other methods in the same class. Therefore, the properties can be accessed there using `dynamic`. :)

Comment: @Timwi: No, the anonymous type is scoped to the method. You can use `dynamic` to access an anonymous object from anywhere, the scope doesn't matter.

Comment: @Timwi, @Guffa: No, you are both wrong; first, the anonymous type is not "scoped" anywhere because it does not have a name and a scope is a region in which an entity may be accessed by name. Second, the unit of code in which two identical anonymous types exhibit type unification is the current compilation -- typically the entire assembly.

Comment: @Guffa: Also, it is not true that only Reflection can be used to access the properties of an anonymous type that has been implicitly converted to object. You can re-obtain the anonymous type in another method by casting the object back to the anonymous type. You have to use the sneaky "cast by example" technique, but it can be done. That said, if you are resorting to such tricks you should be using a nominal type in the first place.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Well, scope is perhaps not the right term to use for it (and actually I didn't use it in my answer). My point is that you can easily access the properties in the anonymous type inside the method, but not outside it.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Fine, I should have checked this first. I assumed that anonymous types would be compiled into private nested types (just like lambda closures and iterator blocks), but apparently they are compiled into top-level types, making them accessible to the entire assembly.

Comment: @Guffa: For `dynamic`, the scope *does* matter. Try it with a (non-anonymous) private nested type and you will see the code inside its outer type can access its properties via `dynamic`, but code outside the outer type cannot. (I tried it.)

Comment: @Timwi: Yes, for private classes it does matter. Outside the scope the properties *should* not be available.

Answer (score 9):

As others have said, the best thing to do here is to make a nominal type. I would suggest that the nominal type have the same characteristics as an anonymous type; that is, you should consider making the type *immutable* and consider making it exhibit *value equality*.

It *is* possible to return an anonymous type as object and then use the instance returned elsewhere using a variety of sneaky techniques. You can cast the object to "dynamic" (in C# 4) and then use the properties of the anonymous type, but this is slow and lacks compile-time type checking.

You can also use the "cast by example" trick, which does get you compile-time type checking.  However, **that trick only works when the anonymous source object and the anonymous example object come from the same assembly**.

```
static T CastByExample<T>(object source, T example) where T : class
{
    return source as T;
}

static object ReturnsAnonymous() { return new { X = 123 }; }

static void DoIt()
{
    object obj = ReturnsAnonymous();
    var example = new { X = 0 };
    var anon = CastByExample(obj, example);
    Console.WriteLine(anon.X); // 123
}
```

See how sneaky that is? We use method type inference and local variable type inference to tell the compiler "these two things are the same type".  This lets you export an anonymous type as object and cast it back to anonymous type.

But you probably should not do this; if you're resorting to such sneaky tricks then you should simply be defining a nominal type in the first place. Also, like I said, the trick  only works if the *example* and the *source* objects were created in code in the same assembly; two "identical" anonymous types in two different assemblies do *not* unify to be the same type.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible as the anonymous class is only valid within the current context. If you need to return an object then you'll need to create a real class.

I'm assuming you left `string` as the return type by accident.

Answer (score 0):

`Anonymous type` are class type that are derived directly from `object`.

You can return it from method as `object` as return type.
Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. Your options are:

1. Define a real class for the return value,
2. Use System.Tuple, or
3. Use out parameters (probably the least good option).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a struct (or class) for this.

```
public struct IdAndName
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;

    public IdAndName(int id, string name)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

You could also use a Tuple<T1, T2>, (but that's not recommended as the properties aren't named.

Answer (score 0):

```
class NewString
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public NewString Test()
{
    return ( new NewString() { ID = 5, Name = "Dave" } );
}
```

:)