# How to pass anonymous type to method as a parameter?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the return type of an anonymous class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466054/whats-the-return-type-of-an-anonymous-class)

I'm creating an anonymous type with query like the following:

Caller code:

```
 var query= from p in _db.ExecuteDataSet(SQL).Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                        select new {
                                       ProductCode = p.Field<string>("PRODUCT_CODE"),
                                       ProductName = p.Field<string>("PRODUCT_NAME")
                                   };
 foreach(var product in query)
 {
     WriteProduct(product);
 }
```

Method is like:

```
void WriteProduct(object prod)
{
  //   access the product
}
```

I fail to get the correct Parameter Type for the `WriteProduct` method. Please help me.

Comment: Anonymous types are pretty much what they're called: they don't have a name. And if it doesn't have a name, you can't refer to it. Make it a full-fledged class or struct if you want to be able to refer to it.

Comment: @zneak: Anonymous types do have a type name that is known at compile time.  You can get it like this: product.GetType().FullName.  That doesn't help the OP, but your comment isn't strictly true.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can.

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Thing(dynamic other)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(other.TheThing);
    }

    private static void Main()
    {
        var things = new { TheThing = "Worked!" };
        Thing(things);
    }
}
```

But as a small, minor detail, **DON'T!**

Anonymous types are anonymous for a reason, they aren't first class entities in your code, they're more of a convenience.  If a type is that important, define it as such.

Answer (score 7):

There are 3 ways to talk to an anonymous type:

- reflection (obtain the properties via `obj.GetType().GetProperties()` / `prop.GetValue(obj, null)`, etc)
- `dynamic` (i.e. `obj.ProductCode` and `obj.ProductType`, for `dynamic obj`) - an optimized and prettier version of the above
- cast-by-example : DO NOT USE

Your `WriteProduct` must use one of those; or alternatively : use something other than an anonymous type; a `Tuple<...>`, maybe (although that tends to make it hard to know what the data *is*) - or an appropriately defined custom interface, class or struct.

Comment: "cast-by-example"? (I won't use it I promise!)

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett there are some nasty ways you can abuse the (guaranteed within a module) fact that two anon types with the same names and same types in the same order will be the same type. For example, you can create a twin value inside the method, and use that to trick generic type inference into typing the unknown value into that type. Messy and really really brittle. http://pastie.org/2953799

Comment: Ahh, clever stuff. I'll definitely not be using that; looks really like some really smelly code!

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you should create a temporary class to store the product.

```
select new TempProduct {
    productCode = p.Field<string>("PRODUCT_CODE"),
    productName = p.Field<string>("PRODUCT_NAME")
};
```

With e.g a class like this

```
public class TempProduct
{
    public String productCode { get; set; }
    public String productName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: +1; I'd make the names have initial caps, even though this is a class with limited usage. `ProductCode` instead of `productCode`.

Comment: Yeah, I had it like that in the beginning, but the coloring might confuse someone since it's colored like a class. But I'm with you here!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly what you are asking for, but your select has only two properties, so how about passing these two to the method?

```
foreach(var product in query) 
{ 
    WriteProduct(product.ProductCode, product.ProductName); 
} 
// ...
void WriteProduct(string productCode, string productName) 
{ 
    // ...
}
```