# Passing IEnumerable data from LINQ as parameter to a method

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I pass an anonymous type to a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55101/how-can-i-pass-an-anonymous-type-to-a-method)

I have the following `LINQ` Statement, whose output has to be processed in another method:

```
var data = from lines in File.ReadAllLines(TrainingDataFile)
                             .Skip(ContainsHeader ? 1 : 0)
           let f = lines.Split(new[] { FieldSeparator }).ToList<String>()
           let target = f[TargetVariablePositionZeroBased]
           select new { F=f, T=target };
```

What should be the datatype of the parameter in the method that will take this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't very easily pass anonymous types around.  You can either create a class, or since your data has only two properties, use a `Tuple`:

```
select new Tuple<List<string>, string> (f, target);
```

If I have the data types correct, then the data type of the parameter would be:

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<List<string>, string>>
```

and you would reference `F` and `T` using the `Tuple` properties `Item1` and `Item2`.

Comment: Apparently, IEnumerable<T> cant take two arguments...its a generic class one 1 argument..so this wont work

Comment: It only has one argument: `Tuple<List<string>, string>`.  Did you try it?

Comment: That was smart:) ..will try that

Comment: @Aadith For a similar example, consider the standard type `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, which implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`. That's perfectly valid: `IEnumerable` has one generic type argument, namely `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`.

Answer (score 8):

You can not return the anonymous data types from a method. You can define a class and return object of that class from query and pass it to target method.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string F {get; set;}
    public string T {get; set;}
}

var data = from lines in File.ReadAllLines(TrainingDataFile)
                                .Skip(ContainsHeader ? 1 : 0)
               let f = lines.Split(new[] { FieldSeparator }).ToList<String>()
               let target = f[TargetVariablePositionZeroBased]
               select new SomeClass { F=f, T=target };
```

You can pass the query result `IEnumerable<SomeClass>` to method as parameter.

```
public void MethodToCall(IEnumerable<SomeClass> someClass)
{

}
```

To call the method by passing the query result (`IEnumerable<SomeClass>`) that is stored in `data` in this sample code

```
MethodToCall(data);
```

Comment: "You can not return the anonymous data types from a method." -- True, but that isn't what the question asks. The question asks to *pass* the anonymous data type *to* a method. That is possible when the method is a generic one. (Whether a generic method is useful here depends on what that method should do.)

Answer (score 3):

1) Just to pass the result of the query, make your function generic, that will do:

```
var data = from lines in File.ReadAllLines(TrainingDataFile)
                         .Skip(ContainsHeader ? 1 : 0)
       let f = lines.Split(new[] { FieldSeparator }).ToList<String>()
       let target = f[TargetVariablePositionZeroBased]
       select new { F=f, T=target };

SomeMethod(data);

public void SomeMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    // ^^choose the return type..
}
```

Simple. If the processing inside the method is something so simple this will do. But you won't be able to access properties `F` and `T` inside the method.

To do so:

2) You can use the "cast by example" trick shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6469199/661933) by Eric. To quote him:

> We use method type inference and local variable type inference to tell
>   the compiler "these two things are the same type". This lets you
>   export an anonymous type as object and cast it back to anonymous type.
>
> ...the trick only works if the example and the source objects were
>   created in code in the same assembly; two "identical" anonymous types
>   in two different assemblies do not unify to be the same type.

```
SomeMethod(data);

public void SomeMethod(IEnumerable<object> enumerable)
{
    var template = new { F = new List<string>(), T = string.Empty };
    foreach (var item in enumerable)
    {
        var anonymousType = item.CastToTypeOf(template);
        //print string.Join(", ", anonymousType.F) + " - " + anonymousType.T //compiles
        //or whatever
    }
}

//a more generic name perhaps is 'CastToTypeOf' as an extension method
public static T CastToTypeOf<T>(this object source, T example) where T : class
{
    return (T)source;
}
```

The catch here is that `SomeMethod` now is tailor made for your anonymous type, since you're specifying a specific type inside the method, so its better to not make the function generic (though you can do) and to give a suitable name for the function.

3) If function is just for your unique type now, I would better have them all wrapped in a single method and not pass at all - no hassle! :)

4) Or you can delegate the action to be done on your anonymous type. So method signature would be like:

```
SomeMethod(data, d => print string.Join(", ", d.F) + " - " + d.T);

public void SomeMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> actor)
{
    foreach (var item in enumerable)
        actor(item);
}
```

If it matters you can have `Func` delegate as well by having one more type argument.

5) Rely on fiddly reflection to get the properties from your anonymous type otherwise.

6) Use `dynamic` keyword on method argument and now you have dynamic typing. Both the above doesnt give you benefits of static typing.

7) You will be better off having a separate class that holds `F` and `T`. And that the best of all. **But ask yourself do they together represent something as an entity**?

8) If not, just pass an `IEnumerable<Tuple>` or `IDictionary` depending on what matters.

---

It all depends on what/how you want to achieve with the method. Personally, I would go for the approach 2 in a hobby project (for the fun involved), but in production code 3, 4, 7, 8 depending on the context.

Comment: or `dynamic`, that will work as well.

Comment: @Yossarian true, but I despise it :)